# jQuery ajax is success but error block is executing

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       jsonp: null,
       jsonpCallback: null
    });

        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'actionName.action',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {},

          success: function(data){  
             alert("success");
         },
          error:function() { 
              alert("error");
         }
    });
```

I'm using the above ajax call. I'm getting the data in response, but the second alert is executing. What might be the wrong here?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Could be the dataType wrong. Are you sure the request successfully returns valid json?

Comment: but i am getting the reponse

Comment: Did you checked what error is being thrown? `error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown); }`

Comment: how i can check the error

Comment: change `alert("error");` to `console.log('error', arguments)` and check the console

Comment: The `error` function will be called if your ajax request returned OK, but returned invalid JSON. Can you check what you're getting back from the server?

Comment: @ArunPJohny SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '............

Comment: You are not returning a valid json.

Comment: how i can check my json is valid or not.Actually in struts2 we will use json as return type

Comment: @PSR Well, JavaScript tried to parse it and it failed. Thus json is not valid. You have to fix that on the server side. It's impossible to say more without seeing the actual data (and how you stringify it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is i am returning a map which contains key as integer,that causes the error.
I changes it from int to string it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using

```
dataType: 'json',
```

jQuery fires the error event if the response cannot be parsed as JSON, even if server returns 200 OK. Check the data returned from the server and make sure it is valid JSON (for test you can use {}).